# How to turn off multiple statements in postgres?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, sql-injection

I think it is a good idea to turn off multiple statements like this to prevent this type of sql-injection.
Example of multiple statements:

```
$query = "UPDATE authors SET author=UPPER(author) WHERE id=1;";
$query .= "UPDATE authors SET author=LOWER(author) WHERE id=2;";
$query .= "UPDATE authors SET author=NULL WHERE id=3;";

pg_query($conn, $query);
```

Is it possible to prevent multiple statements in posgresql settings or for example using posgre's related PHP code?

Or maybe there is any way of parsing SQL queries before passing them to pg_query in order to detect queries which consists of more than one statement?

Comment: count the semi-colons?

Comment: Semi-colons can be used as string values of fields (for example when saving serialized array). Can semi-colons be used somewhere else than string value?

Comment: Parametrise your query and use `pg_query_params( $connection, $querystring, $params);` to invoke it. $params is an array with all the params you want to hand to the query. Querystring is the query with the formal parameters specified as `$1` , `$2`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no way to disable multi-statements in PostgreSQL. Nor, as far as I know, is there any way to do so in the PHP Pg or PDO PostgreSQL drivers.

They aren't your problem anyway. Disabling multi-statements might be a (slight) SQL injection *harm mitigation*, but it wouldn't be any real protection. Consider writeable CTEs, for example, or qualifier removal attacks.

Instead, protect your code properly in the first place. Rigorously use parameterized statements instead of string concatenation, so there's no SQL injection opportunity in the first place. It's not hard to avoid SQL injection, you just have to be a little bit sensible with your coding practices.

Use PDO or `pg_query_params` for all queries, and make sure you don't concatenate text that's come from outside the immediate scope directly into SQL text, use a parameter. Even if it comes from elsewhere in the application and is considered "trusted" ... later refactoring might change that.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php claims that only single-statement queries can be used.

Answer (score -2):

> I think it is a good idea

It is, actually, not.

You have to prevent injections, not multiple queries.

Comment: Isn't this more of a comment than answer?

Comment: I consider this step as additional step to prevent injections (for reinsurance).

Comment: According to binary logic, this step would be unnecessary and useless.